# Stop and Reset Harvest's Tick Counter jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, harvest

Anyone knows how to stop and reset [Harvest's Tick](https://github.com/harvesthq/tick/) counter jQuery plugin? I want to stop counter on specific number and reset to primary start up number.

You can checkout my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pb6dcuqe/).

**HTML Markup:**

```
<span class="tick tick-flip tick-promo">5,000</span>
```

**jQuery Logic:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    startCounter();
});

function startCounter() {
    $('.tick').ticker({
        delay: 1000,
        incremental: 1,
        separators: true
    });
}

var myCounter = setInterval(function resetCounter() {
    var lsCurrentTick = $('.tick').find('.tick-new').text();

    if (lsCurrentTick > 5010) {
        $.fn.ticker.stop();
    }
}, 1000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to [read the code](https://github.com/harvesthq/tick/blob/master/assets/js/tick.js) to figure this out. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pb6dcuqe/18/)

```
$(startCounter);

function startCounter() {
    var tickObj = $('.tick').ticker({
        delay: 1000,
        incremental: 1,
        separators: true
    })[0];
    setInterval(function () {
        if (tickObj.value >= 5002) {
            tickObj.stop();
            tickObj.value = 5000;
            tickObj.start();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

If you are feeling brave you can mess with `Tick.prototype.tick` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pb6dcuqe/17/)

```
function startCounter() {
    var tickObj = $('.tick').ticker({
        delay: 1000,
        incremental: 1,
        separators: true
    })[0];
    tickObj.tick = (function (tick) {
        return function () {
            var ret = tick.call(tickObj);
            if (tickObj.value > 5002) {
                tickObj.stop();
                tickObj.value = 5000;
                tickObj.start();
            }
            return ret;
        };
    }(tickObj.tick));
}
```

Comment: I want to insert every tick into database so, I have create javascript function "insertCounter()" and write down all logic in that function. Now I want to call this function on every tick. Can you please let me know where can I call it???

Comment: You can call the `insertCounter()` function after the `var ret = tick.call(tickObj);` line.

Comment: Hi Robb, Can I use DOT(.) as separator instead of COMMA(,)? When I tried DOT as separator, it behaves like decimal value. Do you have any suggestion to use DOT as separator? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a reference to the ticker and to reset you would have to do

```
ticker[0].stop();
ticker[0].value = 5000;
ticker[0].start();
```

---

Full example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ticker;
    startCounter();
});

function startCounter() {
    ticker = $('.tick').ticker({
        delay: 1000,
        incremental: 1,
        separators: true,
    });
}
var myCounter = setInterval(function resetCounter() {
    var lsCurrentTick = $('.tick').find('.tick-new').text();

    if (lsCurrentTick > 5003) {
        reset();
    }
}, 1000);
function stop(){
    ticker[0].stop();
}
function reset(){
    ticker[0].stop();
    ticker[0].value = 5000;
    ticker[0].start();
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/pb6dcuqe/10/)